# Xscreensaver daemon is not running on display ":0.0"

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, xscreensaver

First time poster, long time answer seeker.

I had to install Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS over the Lubuntu 16.10 due to bugs and other issues (system would crash constantly, display drivers decided to quit working, and the same thing with OpenGL screensavers), and when I open up Xscreensaver, even after either powering on or rebooting the computer, I get this error:

```
Xscreensaver daemon does not seem to be running on display ":0.0" Would you like to run the daemon?
OK Cancel
```

I click OK and the screensaver does run after configuring it and leaving it idle for about 5 minutes (that's the ETA for every computer I have for the screensavers to turn on), but after a reboot, or power off, then on, it goes south. The screensaver doesn't run, the daemon never starts, etc.  Even my laptop running Lubuntu 16.04 has the same issue.

Am I missing any steps?

Laptop Specs:

```
Compaq Presario C700 (727US)
Intel Pentium Dual-Core
2GB DDR2-667
Intel GMA X3100
120GB SSD
Lubuntu 16.04 with KODI (lubuntu-desktop and kodi installed via Ubuntu Server)
Atheros Wireless G
55Wh and 47Wh Batteries
```

Desktop specs:

```
PCChips M871G v1.3 Socket 754 Motherboard
1GB DDR-333
SiS Chipsets (Ethernet, Audio, SATA, IDE)
nVidia Ge-Force 6200 AGP 8x
Toshiba 320GB SATA HDD
Teac 1.44MB 3.5" FDD
Lite-On DVD Burner
Mitsumi 48x CD Drive
TrendNet Wireless G USB
USB 2.0 and FireWire PCI Card (video editing for my DCR-TRV260)
VIA VT6421a AHCI-compliant SATA and IDE controller card
520W Corsair PSU
Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS i386 (32-bit)
```

I'll post updates to see if Xubuntu does, in fact, run the xscreensaver daemon after a reboot.

Update: Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS after a reboot does run the xscreensaver daemon.  I did look in the startup program to see if it was ticked, and it is.  All is well.  Now, I have to figure out why my laptop doesn't run the program and if there is, in fact, a startup program installed or available to install via apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have  Xubuntu, but I installed Lubuntu last week.which is based on Ubuntu and had this same exact issue that was driving me nuts. I tried all the commands possible and yet nothing happened until I myself fixed it.

I started tinkering with the screensaver itself. So, I finally clicked the screensaver button/app, and when the screensaver box with animations came up, I clicked on *file* option, then from the drop down menu clicked **kill daemon**. Then I went to the core applications in my LX Configuration & where it says **screensaver** - the text field next to it was empty - I typed in `xscreensaver` and finally it got fixed.

Hopefully, this might help somehow.

Comment: "Then I went to the core applications in my LX Configuration & where it says screensaver": Can you give us the file path?

Answer (score 0):

In Lubuntu 18: LX Main Menu -> Preferences -> "Default Applications for LX Session" -> Window comes up titled "LXSession Configuration" -> "Core Applications" tab -> In blank next to screensaver, type "xscreensaver".  Close window, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to correctly add Xscreensaver to your startup applications by using the appropriate command. If you rely on the system's default selection from the applications list, it may add "xscreensaver-demo" instead.
The correct command to use is `xscreensaver -no-splash`.

I found this in: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=222659.
For more info you can read: https://go.janleow.com/2022/11/xscreensaver-daemon-doesnt-seem-to-be-running.html.

I hope this works for you!